# UIImageView animated doesn't work properly inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to add a `UIImageView` animated inside an `UICollectionViewCell` so I came up with this code:

```
    import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var items:[String] = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 220/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView)
    }

    lazy var collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        var cv = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: self.flowLayout)
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.bounces = true
        cv.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        cv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        cv.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 220/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 1.0)
        return cv
    }()

    lazy var flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
        var flow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0)
        return flow
    }()


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{

        let width:CGFloat = self.view.bounds.size.width*0.98;
        let height:CGFloat = 150.0;
        return CGSizeMake(width, height)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return self.items.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.imgView.animationImages = ["1","2","3","4","5", "6","7","8"].map{UIImage(named: $0)!}
        cell.imgView.animationDuration = NSTimeInterval(0.8)
        cell.imgView.startAnimating()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
         return true
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "Cell tapped", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        var action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (dd) -> Void in }
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

This is my MainViewController with a `CollectionView` added programmatically.

```
    import UIKit

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addSubview(self.imgView)
    }

    lazy var imgView:UIImageView = {
        var iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        return iv
    }()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.imgView.frame = CGRectMake(6,15,self.frame.width*0.2, self.frame.height*0.8)
    }
}
```

And this is my custom `UICollectionViewCell` with an `UIImageView`

My problem is when you tap a cell the `UIImageView` disappears. Trying to solve the problem I started to look another `UICoolectionView` **delegate** methods. Then I tried to use `shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath`, But If I use this method returning **false** the animation works fine but the collection view stops responding to `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

This is a github repository with a code that shows the issue: https://github.com/gazolla/ImageAnimation (**updated with solution**)

**SOLUTION:**

With matt's help, I made the following changes in my code:

1) add images array to `highlightedAnimationImages` property

```
let animationArray = ["1","2","3","4","5", "6","7","8"].map{UIImage(named: $0)!}
cell.imgView.highlightedAnimationImages = animationArray
```

2) Restart animation when cells are deselected

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CustomCell{
        cell.imgView.startAnimating()
    }
 }
```

3) Restart animation when cells are selected

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.imgView.startAnimating()

    //...

}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

After some tests, I found out that when you **tap and hold** a cell `UIImageView` disappears again, So we have to restart animation in another two methods:

1) didHighlightItemAtIndexPath

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CustomCell{
            cell.imgView.startAnimating()
        }

  }
```

2) didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CustomCell{
        cell.imgView.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use Solution 2.

Comment: Solution 1 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select the cell, the image view looks to its `highlightedAnimationImages`, not its `animationImages`. You didn't set the `highlightedAnimationImages` so you see nothing.

Here's a screencast showing that this can work. The cell is selected when the background is gray (that is its `selectedBackgroundView`) but the animation continues:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, matt. I add `highlightedAnimationImages` into `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and it doesn't work. Should I put this command in another place ?

Comment: I added a github repository with my code in the question.

Comment: You also have to start the animation again.

Comment: Matt, I found out another issue, when you tap and hold a cell sometimes animation disappears. Probably I will have to restart animation in another point. Do you know if we can detect tap and hold uicollectionviewcell ?

Comment: Have you considered using an animated _image_ instead of an animated image _view_? They don't stop ever.

Comment: My book explains it to you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_uiimageview_and_uiimage_animation

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else encounters this nasty bug and the above solutions don't help – try calling `imageView.stopAnimating()` in your cell's `prepareForReuse()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version of Solution 2 from @Sebastian.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
        cell.imgView.startAnimating()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
        cell.imgView.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i did not get the "didDeselectItemAtIndexPath" to work, so my solution to the problem was just to add a button with no function over the picture.

So when you touch the picture, you will touch the button instead.

Answer (score 0):

[The solution 1 and 2 based on Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32356352/419348) gives me an inspiration. When UITableViewCell `isSelected` or `isHighlighted` status changes, it will call `setSelected:animated:` or `setHighlighted:animated` method. So, I override the methods of custom UITableViewCell.

```
class DCFWFailReasonCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Local flag for UIImageView animation.
    fileprivate var isAnimation: Bool = false

    // Setup animation images 
    func configure(animateImage: [UIImage], duration: TimeInterval) {
        imgView.animationImages = animateImage
        imgView.highlightedAnimationImages = animateImage
        
        imgView.animationDuration = duration
        imgView.animationRepeatCount = 0 //< 0 infinite
        
        imgView.startAnimating()

        // imgView has animation.         
        isAnimation = true
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        // 
        if (self.isAnimation) {
            imgView.startAnimating()
        }
    }
    
    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
        
        if (self.isAnimation) {
            imgView.startAnimating()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, works well

```
class MyImageView: UIImageView {
    
    override func stopAnimating() {
        super.stopAnimating()
        startAnimating()
    }
}
```